# Eclipse JFace how to dynamically add SWT view

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin, swt, jface

My view (Show Result) is defined in plugin.xml. Which is working as expected when I run the plugin Show Result widget is getting displayed. Now I want to load the view dynamically based on results. Such as for each result it should load the new Show Result (e.g Show Results1, Show Results2 etc) widget.
Any suggestion on how it can be achieved?

```
<view
    allowMultiple="true"
    class="com.eclipse.plugin.MyResultView"
    icon="icons/res.png"
    id="view1"
    name="Show Results"
    restorable="true">
</view>
```

Comment: That on its own doesn't show the view, have you added it to a perspective using `org.eclipse.ui.perspectiveExtensions` or something like that? You use the `showView` / `hideView` methods of `IWorkbenchPage` to show and hide views.

Comment: @greg-449 Added view part of code

Comment: @greg-449, I am new to SWT sorry for confusion. 
IWorkbench workbench = StudentEclipsePlugin.getInstance().getWorkbench();
 workbench.addWindowListener(new WindowListenerAdapter());
IWorkbenchWindow[] workbenchWindows = workbench.getWorkbenchWindows();
      for (int i = 0; i < workbenchWindows.length; i++) {
        IWorkbenchPage page = workbench.getWorkbenchWindows()[i].getActivePage();
          page.addSelectionListener(new SelectionListener());    }}

Comment: @greg-449 yeah it make sense in just hard coding view id. How can I load multiple views dynamically.

Comment: @greg-449 thing is I may not know how many secondary id's I will be needing it defined dynamically can't hard code it.

Comment: @greg-449 ok I will try that out. How do I define secondary Id in plugin.xml

Comment: @greg-449 You made my day, appreciate your help :) Is there any way I change the view name also dynamically ? right now Iam getting same view name widgets I want to change it.

Comment: ViewPart.setPartName - see my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to show multiple instances of the same view use the

```
IViewPart showView(String viewId, String secondaryId, int mode);
```

method of `IWorkbenchPage`. The view needs to be defined with `allowMultiple="true"` in the plugin.xml.

The `secondaryId` is a arbitrary string that distinguishes the views, it can have any value (except it should not contain a `:`).

To set the name of the view call the `ViewPart.setPartName(String name)` method in the view part.